# Adjust means based on sample size

Tags: hypothesis-testing, bayesian, sample-size, weighted-mean

I have a population of National Teams (32), and parameter (mean) that I want to measure for each team, aggregated per match.

For example: I get the mean scouts for all strikers for each team, per match, and then I get the the mean (or median) for all team matches.

---

Now, one group of teams have played 18 matches and another group has played only 8 matches for the World Cup Qualifying.

I have an hypothesis that, for two teams with equal mean value, the one with larger sample size (18) should be ranked higher.

---

```
less_than_8 = all_stats[all_stats['games']<=8]
```

I get values:

```
3     0.610759
7     0.579832
14    0.537579
20    0.346510
25    0.403606
27    0.536443
```

and with:

```
sns.displot(less_than_8, x="avg_attack",kind='kde',bw_adjust=2)
```

I plot:

[image]

with a mean of `0.5024547681196802`

---

Now, for:

```
more_than_18 = all_stats[all_stats['games']>=18]
```

I get values:

```
0     0.148860
1     0.330585
4     0.097578
6     0.518595
8     0.220798
11    0.200142
12    0.297721
15    0.256037
17    0.195157
18    0.176994
19    0.267094
21    0.295228
22    0.248932
23    0.420940
24    0.148860
28    0.297721
30    0.350516
31    0.205128
```

and I plot the curve:

[image]

which a lower mean, of `0.25982701104003497`.

---

It seems clear that sample size does affect the mean, diminishing it as size increases.

Is there a way I can adjust the means of larger sample size AS IF they were being calculated on a smaller sample size, or vice versa, using prior and posteriori assumptions?

Many thanks

Comment: one way to deal with this is empirical Bayes; see here for a batting average example: http://varianceexplained.org/r/empirical_bayes_baseball/